# TouchableHighlight affects padding

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-web

I have react-native-web project.
A problem I'm having is that when a `TouchableHighlight` is pressed, the padding of all the children elements is removed.

Before the touch, the inspector shows proper padding, after the touch padding is 0. I've tried wrapping the `Text` in a `View` component, and unwrapping it as well.

I'm at a loss here

```
const bS : ViewStyle = {
paddingTop: 5,
paddingLeft: 5,
paddingRight: 5,
paddingBottom: 5,

flexDirection: "column",
justifyContent: "center",
width: '100%',
height: '100%'
}

export default function TextButton(props: {title: string, onPress: () => any}) {

return <TouchableHighlight style={s.touch} underlayColor={'#000000'} onPress={props.onPress}>
  <View style={bS}>
    <Text>{props.title}</Text>
  </View>
  </TouchableHighlight>
}
```

**EDIT**
As asked, I added the code onto CodeSandbox, but it works perfectly fine!
https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-golick-uwl6f?fontsize=14

**EDIT 2**
The problem comes when `React` is imported from `react-native`. The problem goes away when `React` is imported from `react`

Comment: can you upload your code on codesandbox?

Comment: @VahidAl here you go https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-golick-uwl6f?fontsize=14

Comment: You must always import React from react package! no matter you wanna use react-dom, react-native or react-dom/server!